# How to create string literal type from interface key and key value

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have an interface and enum

```
enum Destination = {
 Home = 'home',
 Cafe = 'cafe'
}

interface Payload {
 apiVersion: string;
 destination: Destination;
 email?: string;
}
```

And I want to create a template literal type that takes the interface key as the opening and closing tag, and the key value as the tag value.

```
const condensedPayload: CondensedPayload = '<payload><apiVersion>2.1</apiVersion><destination>home</destination><email>asd@asd.com</email></payload>'
```

I've tried to create `CondensedPayload` like this

```
type CondensedPayload = `<payload><${keyof Payload}>${Payload[keyof Payload]}</${keyof Payload}></payload>`
```

The result:

1. The closing tag name which is not the same as the opening tag name or vice versa, doesn't get an error

   - `const payload: CondensedPayload = '<payload><apiVersion>2.0</destination></payload>' // no error`
2. Not inserting required key doesn't get an error

   - `const payload: CondensedPayload = '<payload><email>asd@asd.com</email></payload>' // no error`
3. Inserted only one required key doesn't get an error

   - `const payload: CondensedPayload = '<payload><apiVersion>2.0</apiVersion><email>asd@asd.com</email></payload>' // no error`
4. Insert string outside `Destination` enum on `<destination>some string</destination>` doesn't get an error

Is there a way to match the opening, closing, and value like maybe iterate the `keyof Payload` and value type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Should you do it? Probably not...

The following solution will generate all possible combinations of string literal types which are valid for a given `Payload` type.

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never

type OptionalProps<T extends object> = Exclude<{
  [K in keyof T]: T extends Record<K, T[K]>
    ? never
    : K
}[keyof T], undefined>

type AllPermutations<T extends string, O extends string> = [T] extends [keyof T] ? [] : {
  [K in T]: 
    K extends O 
      ? [
          ...(AllPermutations<Exclude<T, K>, O> extends infer U extends string[] 
            ? U 
            : never)
        ]
        | [
            K, ...(AllPermutations<Exclude<T, K>, O> extends infer U extends string[] 
              ? U 
              : never)
          ]
      : [
          K, ...(AllPermutations<Exclude<T, K>, O> extends infer U extends string[] 
            ? U 
            : never)
        ]
}[T]

type Join<T extends string[]> = 
  T extends [infer L extends string, ...infer R extends string[]]
    ? `${L}${Join<R>}`
    : ""

type CreatePayloadString<T extends string[], P extends Record<string, any>> = 
  T extends [infer L extends string, ...infer R extends string[]]
    ? `<${L}>${P[L & keyof P]}</${L}>${CreatePayloadString<R, P>}` 
    : ""

type CondensedPayload = {
  [K in AllPermutations<keyof Payload, OptionalProps<Payload>> as Join<K>]: 
    `<payload>${CreatePayloadString<K, Payload>}</payload>`
} extends infer O ? O[keyof O] : never
```

Some tests:

```
// Error 
const payload1: CondensedPayload = '<payload><apiVersion>2.0</destination></payload>'
const payload2: CondensedPayload = '<payload><email>asd@asd.com</email></payload>'
const payload3: CondensedPayload = '<payload><apiVersion>2.0</apiVersion><email>asd@asd.com</email></payload>'
const payload4: CondensedPayload = '<payload><apiVersion>abc</apiVersion><destination>some string</destination></payload>'

// Valid
const payload4: CondensedPayload = '<payload><apiVersion>abc</apiVersion><destination>home</destination></payload>'
```

But seriously, use an XML parser for stuff like this or even better: Don't use XML.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=53&pc=39#code/KYOwrgtgBAIsDOAXAliAhig9iKBvAUFFABKYTBQC8UA5ABZnA0A0hUAwmgGYXU0DG3JvgC++fKkTAATlzT8KABTQBPADaY0AEzxs0AB2QA1GfGTYAXFCTTUAcwDcbLQhTosIK3CSoM5kGzAEGjIagD8Vjb2TmL4iCr6FACiAB76aCBaADwAKgB8VFA5UMApUpnwUKg80lAAqlBheFAA2gDSVTgA1sAqmFz1ALpWde2DUCJQViDAAG4y4vGJUADy+h5oaorSmPrwuSVloFqVmABGAFbA-IgF1Kn8amAuWQRE7Z1QPX0DOcNFh3KJygACVrphpNk2swimM8mwiE0ZvNpAiplA2qIWt9+kVBjCwJlgFxUMAtPC4gkKABBNRbGQQMCIPzYfbFUpAypREB2GErQHHLmIWw8u6tP4CiqtHG-cZNFrjKxvVodVB4qxojocwWrKBoxGtfVEY0AOjNAApafTpIzmR59g8ni8cjC2nk+QVtVLqjJ6pLgdy7Aq9cbQ2Gmg0jWH0ciZABKKNQQaJgA+huj0ehUDNJstdMUDKZLJADpSj2ewFyrvdq09R29IBqfq9AeF9mDiejEZDGej0zm8c7SaNVhaQ6zObz1ttxdL5ed1Y9-sqPtqDRbQpFQfGQ4Nkd7of7KITveTIhaf0WVKgAClMKgDhvrG2eQqxWx2fXgS1V1AADLLs+W4wjmv4goBgYKsmoZNAABgAJLgf4iIhd4PiCeQiLBaJWAARLhV7LOw0jABgwDKOomhaAAyi+diPl+m7tviUCKIBYL8BC2SBjCGQqHk75EJ+nKtL+AFPjx2ZmmBEF0VBaJwVkiHIXkiGKC0AEAGRfL0uKKIMIhZAA9MpIiqbgxGkVIFEaNotFblkIIwoomGwT2RB4QRlJEdgLglmSNlUYUyofGqVoFjaRb2lkMqsaotlaHy6z+Js2y7PsgXaAJUBoJUaEgFkbr-GisFZOklFZYhllkZlNF0YVznxVRmHGeVCV5NhkxPr+-JNCs2K6QMKyKlAsaouInElogUBtVRACMVjsL5oDwAFTXaIUNBlet5JZAYximP4eQAEwmgADMZLg+O4R2tTteQ0Pgk1IDNO3HYty3+VotWbdtFW7UEIRqHkuVaAAAqDJqcRAxmA6EeR3f9D1Pay02zdoADMH1El9P18H97V7YYJjSGY2Anedxn7STZMgAjcPA6DEPwFoUNkLDwTw4j7WPc9aM7QALNjfmrd9O2-eju3U4d5NoGc-BU8TMt01kV1uMWeTwIwQH2Jdri+B4CNGZLyMo1Nr3-QArMLK1rf9Ev3UTB2k0dcsK0Z0su+Tqv6zd5MMOQevXRr3PNTQQA)

Comment: Damn that's a lot lol thanks man. I'm working with 3rd party company which still use XML, and my team want to avoid adding XML parser just for this case lol. Btw, Are there any resources to learn how to create types like yours did? I'm confused reading what you created 

Comment: very impressive!

Comment: @JelmaLieur. I guess there is no straight-forward to deeply learn TypeScript. A good starting point may be these [type challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges#challenges) which start of with easy tasks to get started. This [blog](https://catchts.com/) also helped a lot.